# URL rewriting using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How to rewrite the url in htaccess

www.mywebsite.com/category.php?name="richard" change to www.mywebsite.com/richard/

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to achieve your requirement.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=(.*)
RewriteRule category\.php$ /%1/
```

Hope this helps you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you used any PHP frameworks(like the codenigter... etc)?
You can try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category.php/name=$1 [L]
```